# MySQL Query - get records based on current date

Tags: php, mysql

I am setting a Cron and I want to do various of functions on records which match the current day

**My `users` table:**

```
Username      registration_date    expiration_date
behz4d        2012-01-19 21:55:44  2013-01-23 11:15:24
test          2012-05-24 17:42:13  2013-04-12 17:23:19
...
```

Now I want to get the users which their `expiration_date` is `TODAY`
I simply could query the tables, get their `expiration_date` in an array, and compare that date with today date, like:

```
$current_date = date("Y-m-d");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $users_array[] = $row['username'] . "->" . substr($row['expiration_date'], 0, 10);// since I don't care about the exact time, I need to get the users who their expiration DAY is today 
}
foreach($users_array $username as $expiration_date){
    if($expiration_date == $current_date)
         $my_target_users[] = $username;
}
```

But this seems a little odd, I mean there should be another way...

Is there anyway that I could say like `expiration_date = TODAY` ?

Anybody could help me with this?
Thanks in advance

---

**UPDATE:**

How about getting users who their expiration day is 3 days from today? I want to send an email to them and let them know that their account will be expired in 3 days...
Should I just do:

```
... WHERE expiration_date >= CURRENT_DATE AND expiration_date < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 3 DAYS
```

!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```sql
SELECT username FROM users WHERE DATE(expiration_date) = CURRENT_DATE
```

However, this requires a(n inefficient) full table scan. If you have an index on `expiration_date`, you should instead use:

```sql
SELECT username
FROM   users
WHERE  expiration_date >= CURRENT_DATE
   AND expiration_date <  CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE` ? isn't it `CURDATE()` ?

Comment: @Glavić: [`CURRENT_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date) is a (SQL standard) alias.

Comment: Jep, I just tested this constant `SELECT CURRENT_DATE` and it returns current date ;-) didn't know that, I always use `CURDATE()` function. Tnx

Comment: Rhank @eggyal, it worked, I got a question, why this needs an index?! when we should index columns? thanks

Comment: @behz4d: You should consider adding indexes when fetching data becomes too slow for your needs.

Comment: @behz4d: Your proposal will give you all accounts that expire *within* the next three days, *including* those that expire today.

Comment: @behz4d: `WHERE expiration_date >= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 3 DAY AND expiration_date < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 4 DAY`