# No result found in query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm getting an error in my query, and I'm unable to detect the source of the problem.

Here is the query:-

```
$query = "SELECT useraccount.Username, tariff.Name as tariffs, 
    sum(energyconsumption.ElecEnergy)
    FROM useraccount
    INNER JOIN tariff 
ON useraccount.tariffs = tariff.id
INNER JOIN energyconsumption
ON energyconsumption.User = useraccount.id
WHERE Date = CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY useraccount.Username, tariff.Name as tariffs";
```

Following the query I've code that stores the output in an array:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $r = array();
        if($result->num_rows){

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                array_push($r, array( 'Username' => $row['Username'],
                'TariffName' => $row['tariffs'], 'ElecConsump' => $row['ElecEnergy']


                ));

                }

        } echo json_encode(array('results' => $r));
```

Im getting an error in the following line: if($result->num_rows)

This is the output when executing the query:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\Client\newone.php on line 22
{"results":[]}

Please note:

This was the output i intially had:

```
{"results":[{"Username":"absc868","TariffName":"s1","ElecConsump":"2000"},  
{"Username":"absc868","TariffName":"s1","ElecConsump":"1900"}]}
```

But with this new query I have written above, I am trying to produce this output
 I am trying to produce the following output:
= {"results":[{"Username":"absc868","TariffName":"s1","ElecConsump":"3900"}

**That being, a result set that only has 1 entry, for username, tariff and elecconsump, rather than 2 entries for username, tariff and elecconsump**

Thank you once again to all those who have read and contributed to this thread

Comment: run the query directly into phpmyadmin and check it works there or giving any error?

Comment: non-object means your query failed; check for errors `mysqli_error($conn)`.

Comment: Search the error message on Google and you'll find many, *many*, ***many*** duplicate questions.  The problem is that the database query is failing.  You need to check for errors from the database before assuming success.

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE` is obviously a function.

Comment: @u_mulder   `CURRENT_DATE` is a (SQL standard) alias:-  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14417808/4248328

Comment: @u_mulder As per the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date *"CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_DATE() are synonyms for CURDATE()."* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- wow, didn't know it. Always learn something new)

Comment: @u_mulder Yeah, I thought so too before. Nobody can say that we stop to learn from one another (or stop learning period) ;-) *Cheers* I include myself in that.

Comment: @Anant I already pinged u_mulder ;-) before you *lol*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is the `as` in the `GROUP BY`.  I would recommend that you use table aliases:

```
SELECT ua.Username, t.Name as tariffs,
       SUM(ec.ElecEnergy) as ElecEnergy
FROM useraccount ua INNER JOIN
     tariff t
     ON ua.tariffs = t.id INNER JOIN
     energyconsumption ec
     ON ec.User = ua.id
WHERE Date = CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY ua.Username, t.Name;
```

Comment: Hi, I've just tried it, and it workds 90%. I'm getting the correct output for username and tariff, however for elecconsump, its giving me a null value. The name of the table that contains all the energy consumption values is "energyconsumption"

Comment: because you didn't give it any name. use `SUM(ec.ElecEnergy) AS elecconsump` and in your PHP code you can use `$row['elecconsump']`

Comment: @Dekel, hmm, I've tried that, but I'm still getting a null value for it.

Comment: did you check for errors like already commented on the question?

Comment: @Dekel yep. Its interesting, why would there be a null value being returned for just ElecConsump, when values are being populated for the other columns.

Comment: maybe because you didn't select that column?